# How to use a select tag with the selected option in the controller in codeignator?

Tags: php, html, if-statement, codeigniter-3

I am using Codeigniter. In the controller, I have a select tag something like

```
  $action='<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="'.$row->bank_id.'">
           <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
           <option value="1">Disbursed </option>
           <option value="2">Files sumitted </option>
           <option value="3">Pendency </option>
           <option value="4">Approved</option>
           <option value="5">Rejected</option>
           <option value="6">Dropped</option>
           </select>';
```

Now what I am doing is, I have to use an `if` condition to show the selected option. So I tried:

```
<option value="1"'if($row->status == "1"){ echo "selected"; }'>Disbursed </option>
```

but it is showing the wrong results.

Should I create something like this:

```
$action='<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="'.$row->bank_id.'">
<option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
<option value="1"';
 if($row->b_filestatus == "1"){ echo "selected"; }
 $action='>Disbursed </option>
 <!--more here-->
```

or should I use an altogether different method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this

```
$action='<select name="pp_fileStatus[]" class="form-control multipleselect wip_fileStatus" data-id="'.$row->bank_id.'">
           <option value="" disabled selected>File Status</option>
           <option value="1"'. ($row->status == "1"?'selected':'').' >Disbursed </option>
           <option value="2"'. ($row->status == "2"?'selected':'').'>Files sumitted </option>
           <option value="3"'. ($row->status == "3"?'selected':'').'>Pendency </option>
           <option value="4"'. ($row->status == "4"?'selected':'').'>Approved</option>
           <option value="5"'. ($row->status == "5"?'selected':'').'>Rejected</option>
           <option value="6"'. ($row->status == "6"?'selected':'').'>Dropped</option>
           </select>';
```